# How to disable Samsung Pass Autofill for TextInputEditText?

Tags: android

I have put importantForAutofill noExcludeDescendants but it still popping up the auto email fill. Only happens on Samsung Devices. Samsung Pass Autofill appear even if i set inputType = number.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_verification_code"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```